# How to create a critical section only for some processes in Open/Microsoft MPI using C++?

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I am new to MPI and wanted to find out how to create a critical section for only a few of the running processes. I know that I can create one like this for ALL processes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    std::cout << "RANK " << rank << " PRINTS " << i << std::endl;
}
```

However this would not work if at least one process wouldn't trigger MPI_Barrier(). So let's say I did this:

```
if(rank > 0)
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    std::cout << "RANK " << rank << " PRINTS " << i << std::endl;
}
```

This would crash as the 0th processes would skip over the loop. So how do I allow all other processes to print synchronously and do something else with the 0th process (let's say wait for a message when all the printing is over)?

Comment: There is no global ordering of the stdout from the different MPI tasks. if you want to `MPI_Barrier()` with all the ranks except `0`, you first need to create a communicator that contains these ranks, and then use it as the argument of `MPI_Barrier()`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I'm assuming that by "create a communicator that contains these ranks" you mean to call MPI_Comm_split() to separate the ranks by the so called "color" and then filter them by their world rank in the end?

Comment: There are various ways to create communicators, and `MPI_Comm_split()` is the simplest and best fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@Gilles Gouaillardet** pointed out, you can use `MPI_Comm_split` to create a communicator without rank 0. `MPI_Barrier` can be called with this new communicator to synchronise the remaining processes. Rank 0, after doing it's operations can call barrier over `COMM_WORLD` and wait for the remaining processes to call it.

Remaining processes, say 1 to N, can execute a code region sequentially (by the way not a MPI approach) by using a `for loop` iterating over `1` to `N` and an `if` block which executes the code region based on `rank` and `MPI_Barrier` as seen in the below example.

```
MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD,color,key,newcomm) // create new comm without rank 0
if(rank>0) {
  for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i)
   {
    if(rank == i) { // Critical region. Only one rank can enter here at a time. Here it enters sequentially from 0 to size
       std::cout << "RANK " << rank << " PRINTS " << i << std::endl; // After calling Critical Session Part, call barrier to signal other processes.
       MPI_Barrier(newcomm);
    } else {
       MPI_Barrier(newcomm); // all other proesses (except rank == i) should wait and do not enter the critical region
    }
   }
       MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);// This barrier will be called with rank 0         
} else {
       //do some work for rank 0
       // wait for the rest of the processes
       MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);         
}
```

Another approach (without creating a new communicator) is you can use the concept of sending the message in ring (ring broadcast).

```
if (rank == 0) {
    value = 1; 
    MPI_Send( &value, 1, MPI_INT, rank + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    // Do something useful
}
else {
    MPI_Recv( &value, 1, MPI_INT, rank - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, 
          &status );
    if (rank < size - 1){ 
    //criticalregion
    MPI_Send( &value, 1, MPI_INT, rank + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    }
}
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Here, `rank 0` send a message to `rank 1` which in turn send to `rank 2` and so on. This way, after receiving the message, the processes can execute the code sequentially (critical region) and then send the message to a higher rank and trigger the execution.

Comment: Thank You! After @Gilles Gouaillardet pointed out creating new comms I've got it working but the ring technique is something I haven't seen before and something that I'll look into while learning MPI.

Comment: Keep in mind that even if `printf()` are ordered on different tasks via `MPI_Barrier()`, MPI does not guarantee you whatsoever that the final output will be ordered. If you really want ordered output, then use the ring technique and have only one rank issue the `printf()`.